# Compute the one-parameter subgroups and the exponential map of the Heisenberg group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, heisenberg-group

For the Heisenberg group

$
H = 
            \{ \begin{bmatrix}
              1 & x & y\\
              0 & 1 & z\\
              0 & 0 & 1
              \end{bmatrix} | \:x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}
$

compute  the one-parameter subgroups and the exponential map.

I have so far found a basis $B = \{ \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}, x \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\}$ for the left-invariant vector-fields on H. But I can't manage to find the corresponding integral-curves.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Update:
I found 
$
c^{1}(t) = 
             \begin{bmatrix}
              1 & x+t & y\\
              0 & 1 & z\\
              0 & 0 & 1
              \end{bmatrix}
$ and $c^2(t) =  \begin{bmatrix}
              1 & x& y+t\\
              0 & 1 & z\\
              0 & 0 & 1
              \end{bmatrix}$ but still struggling with the third.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't a basis like this be easier:
$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0 
\end{pmatrix}, Y = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0 
\end{pmatrix}, Z = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

General elements of the Heisenberg Lie algebra are of the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&a&c\\
0&0&b\\
0&0&0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This has exponential:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&a&\frac{1}{2}ab+c\\
0&1&b\\
0&0&1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So a generic one parameter subgroup is of  the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&at&\frac{1}{2} abt^2+ct\\
0&1&bt\\
0&0&1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{1}{2}\cdot a\cdot b$. But otherwise thank you for your help ! I was stuck with this overly complicated basis...